# How to adjust labels position in geom_line in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(df[df$rodzaj_zabudowy != is.na(df$rodzaj_zabudowy),  aes(x=rok_budowy_cat, y=sr_cena, group=rodzaj_zabudowy)) +
   geom_line(aes(color=rodzaj_zabudowy)) +
   geom_text(stat= "count", aes(label = ..count.., y=..count..),  position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000000))
```

It works fine with geom_bar, but I cant figure out how to do it properly with geom_line.

[image: here's how it looks, first x category labels is how I'd like it to look more or less]

Comment: It will be easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.